# How is the number of channels adjusted in efficientnet

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I was reading the code at efficientnet and was shocked by its clever ideas. But I don't quite understand how it adjusts the number of channels.

```
def round_filters(filters, width_coefficient, depth_divisor):

  filters *= width_coefficient
  new_filters = int(filters + depth_divisor / 2) // depth_divisor * depth_divisor
  new_filters = max(depth_divisor, new_filters)
  # Make sure that round down does not go down by more than 10%.
  if new_filters < 0.9 * filters:
     new_filters += depth_divisor
  return int(new_filters)
```

I know the number of channels has to be adjusted by the width factor, but why do I do the following? What is `depth_divisor`?

Answer (score 1):

It's making the scaled width divisible by `depth_divisor`. You can view as rounding the scaled width to the nearest multiple of `depth_divisor` with some additional consideration (round up when going down more than 10%). In almost all applications of this function in various MobileNets and EfficientNets the depth_divisor is 8.

Why 8? Mostly due to the constraints of common hardware accelerators like GPU and TPU. See a recent cuDNN developer guide and count the number of 'multiple of 8', 'multiple of 32', etc guidelines for optimal performance of certain operations:

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html

> For algorithms other than *_ALGO_WINOGRAD_NONFUSED, when the following
>   requirements are met, the cuDNN library will trigger the Tensor Core
>   operations:
>
> - Input, filter, and output descriptors (xDesc, yDesc,
>     wDesc, dxDesc, dyDesc and dwDesc as applicable) are of the dataType =
>     CUDNN_DATA_HALF (i.e., FP16). For FP32 dataType see FP32-to-FP16
>     Conversion.
> - The number of input and output feature maps (i.e., channel dimension
>     C) is a multiple of 8. When the channel dimension is not a multiple of
>     8, see Padding.
> - The filter is of type CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW or CUDNN_TENSOR_NHWC.
> - If using a filter of type CUDNN_TENSOR_NHWC, then the input, filter,
>     and output data pointers (X, Y, W, dX, dY, and dW as applicable) are
>     aligned to 128-bit boundaries.